# Colspan is disturbing table layout

Tags: html, html-table

Please see below html:

```
      <table style="width: 700px;table-layout: fixed ; margin-top: 30px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr class="tableHeader">
          <td width="220px">Event Name</td>

          <td width="120px">City</td>
          <td width="77px">Date</td>
          <td width="110px">Price</td>
          <td width="80px">Status</td>
          <td width="60px">Select</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div style="overflow: auto;height: 360px; width: 730px;">
        <table style='width: 700px;table-layout: fixed;' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
                <tr >
                    <td colspan='6' >adnanpo </td>
                </tr>
                <tr >
                    <td width='220px' >adnanpo </td>
                    <td width='120px' > </td>
                    <td width='77px' >04/20/2012 </td>
                    <td width='110px' >USD $30.00 </td>
                    <td width='80px' >Paid </td>
                    <td width='60px' >
                        <input class='orgOkButton' type='button' id='btnOpenOrder' name='btnOpenOrder' onclick='return openOrderWindow('/RealResource/submitorder.aspx?OId=35731&EvtId=771')</td> 
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Below part is casuing the issue:

```
                <tr >
                    <td colspan='6' >adnanpo </td>
                </tr>
```

[image]

Please sse the image, the column width is disturbed!! Please help me to fix it!

Comment: What's the problem? The <tr> you are showing us is rendering as you are telling it to. What do you wish for it to appear as?

Comment: Why are you using separate tables for the headings and values?

Comment: you have an unclosed `input` tag here - `<input class='orgOkButton' type='button' id='btnOpenOrder' name='btnOpenOrder' onclick='return openOrderWindow('/RealResource/submitorder.aspx?OId=35731&EvtId=771')</td>`

Comment: let me apply all the solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove 'table-layout' property in your second table and it will work fine. And close you input element (`onclick="return openOrderWindow('/RealResource/submitorder.aspx?OId=35731&EvtId=771')"/>`)

Answer (score 4):

The obvious solution is to remove the `tr` element that causes the problem. It does not seem to have a function here. If you just want some spacer there, put a `div` element between the two tables.

The problem arises because `table-layout: fixed` tells the browser to decide on column widths according to the **first** row, if widths have not been set in certain other ways. Here the first row has just one cell that spans all columns, and then the defined behavior is to divide the width evenly between the columns.

Alternatively, set the column widths explicitly, e.g. using

```
    <col width=220>
    <col width=120>
```

etc. right after each `<table>` tag. But make sure that the sums of the widths add up to the number you set as the total width of the table (they currently don’t). When `col` elements are used that way to set all column widths, browsers will use those exact widths without questioning (which may cause problems, but I presume you have considered them).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you are worried to the fact that your columns are not aligning to the top.

Let me first suggest that you use the below CSS:

```
table { empty-cells: show; }
```

This will allow the empty cell you have to fill in the space. (otherwise you can just put an `&nbsp;` in it's blank space).

Also, I suggest you use one continuous table if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Close your input-tag - the > is missing. If the problem is still there we can look further.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this will be the case by using `colspan` in the "first row" of a table. To get around this you could do something like this (again just for the first row - you can use `colspan` fine further down):

```
                <tr>
                    <td width="220px"><div style="position:absolute;width:220px;">adnanpo</div></td>
                    <td width="120px"></td>
                    <td width="77px"></td>
                    <td width="110px"></td>
                    <td width="80px"></td>
                    <td width="60px"></td> 
                </tr>
```